# How to find the sum of an infinite geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

The formula is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 180 \Big(\frac{3}{5}\Big)^{n-1}$$

How would I find the infinite sum

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I think you are asking for the sum of a geometric series. If you search for that you will find lots of references.

Comment: What is $n$? Is the formula for the $n^{\text {th}}$ term or the sum of the first $n$ terms?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the problem is this
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 180 \Big(\frac{3}{5}\Big)^{n-1}$$
You solve it in the following way. Factor out the $180$ from the sum to get
$$180 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{3}{5}\Big)^{n-1}$$
The sum of an infinite geometric series is $\frac{a_1}{1-r}$, where $a_1$ is the first term and $r$ is the common ratio. In this case, $a_1 = 1$ and $r =\frac{3}{5}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{3}{5}\Big)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{5}} =  \frac{1}{\frac{2}{5}} = \frac{5}{2}$$
And then multiply by $180$:
$$180 * \frac{5}{2} = 450$$
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 180 \Big(\frac{3}{5}\Big)^{n-1} = 450$$